# Interactive / Linked Charting

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

If I had three charts, position, velocity & acceleration, and position is calculated from user input, with velocity and acceleration being derived from it.

Using c#, what approaches could be used to easily manipulate some points on any of those plots by dragging them vertically, so that the others dynamically update?

I can deal with the calculus and smoothing technique required for my application but require advice on making the plots interactive and dynamic.